# How to retrieve values from dot net webservices giving json output?

Tags: .net, ios

In my app i am using SBJson for parsing the values. The web services are developed in dot net. With php web services the code was working quite fine but with dot net web services this is not showing the response values. There is no error or exception or warning in the code.

This is the JSON Output of the web service:

> { "Head":[ { "id":"0","msg":"Username or Password Not Match"} ]}

the user name password is wrong here but my code is not even returning any wrong value.

This one is my code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@&username=%@&password=%@",key.text,[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];
NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jabdcdfddfsd.aspx"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", postData);

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSLog(@"%@",postLength);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSLog(@"%@",request);
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",response);

NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
{
    NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData)
```

Help Me Out. the responseData is printing nothing. There is any problem in my code or the problem is on other end i mean in dotnet web service.

Comment: the urlData is not nil and urlData.length>0 and it is NSUTF8StringEncoding encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if the code worked fine with the old php webservice you should take a long hard look at your .Net webservice. It is highly likely that it is different in some respect. Try using something like the [Chrome Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) to see how each webservice responds.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Stig Brautaset but i am not getting what to see in this Chrome Advanced REST

Comment: Put in the URL you are calling from your app. Compare the output from your two services, with the same input. Are they the same?

Comment: `(
        {
        id = 0;
        msg = "Username or Password Not Match";
    }
)` can you tell me please how i can retrieve the value of "id" from this array

Comment: my actual problem is the line above i have parsed in the form of NSMutable array from an dictionary now i want to remove these () brakets. @Stig Brautaset